# Unit test hyperledger fabric chaincode (GetPrivateData)

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is there any way to unit test private data in hyperledger fabric chaincode? I found testing files for chaincode without private data.

[Chaincode Test](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.1/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example04/chaincode_example04_test.go)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are, one of them are [Marble Example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/chaincode/marbles02_private/go/marbles_chaincode_private.go). You can find the documentation at [Using Private Data in Fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/private_data_tutorial.html)